# ORA-43853 when creating a xml column stored as binary within an Oracle table

Tags: xml, oracle, binary, blob, oracle12c

I am trying to create a table in Oracle through the command:

```
CREATE TABLE xml_binary (
   id    NUMBER,
   fv  XMLTYPE)
   XMLTYPE fv STORE AS BINARY XML
      XMLSCHEMA "http://www.example.com/fvInteger_binary.xsd"
      ELEMENT "ROOT";
```

However, I get the error:

> ORA-43853: SECUREFILE lobs cannot be used in non-ASSM tablespace

I found in [this forum](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/message/13484355#13484355) a solution which would be to ignore the error through the command:

> ALTER SYSTEM SET db_securefile = 'IGNORE;

I do not think it is a good solution, however.

What can I do in order to solve it properly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Securefile can be created only on ASSM tablespace.

```
SELECT tablespace_name,  segment_space_management
      FROM dba_tablespaces;
```

segment_space_management = auto = ASSM-tablespace.

`db_securefile = 'IGNORE'` works in that way. After restart, the db will ignore information about SF and it will create basicfile.

Solution:

1) Store binaryxml in basicfile.

```
XMLTYPE fv STORE AS BASICFILE BINARY XML
```

2) Store binaryxml in securefile in assm tablespace.

```
 XMLTYPE fv STORE AS securefile BINARY XML(tablespace assm_tablespace)
```